# Omitir parámetros de query si estos son nulos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo un Link que al presionarlo conduce a una url dentro de mi aplicacion. A esta url quiero pasarle parametros, entonces tengo una funcion:

```
function handleUrl() {
    return {
      pathname: slug
      query: {
        checkin: urlDates.start,
        checkout: urlDates.end,
      },
    };
  }
```

Si yo en mi app selecciono fechas de un calendario, `urlDates.start` y `urlDates.end` toman valores.

Luego hago click en el Link mencionado al principio, y me redirige a:

> http://localhost/url?checkin=10-2-2022&checkout=10-10-2022

Esto esta perfecto, pero si yo no tengo fechas seleccionadas, la url es:

> http://localhost/url?checkin=&checkout=

**Entonces mi pregunta es esta:** Si yo no tengo fechas seleccionadas, hay alguna forma de evitar enviar el parámetro vacío, es decir, omitir poner `?&checkin=&checkout=` y que solo sea `http://localhost/url`

> Por el momento puse simplemente un `if` en la función `handleUrl` que retorne solo el `pathname` si encuentra nulos los valores `checkin` y `checkout` pero yo en un futuro quiero tener muchos mas parámetros, y no quiero tener una condición gigante que se vaya agrandando a medida que crezcan la cantidad de parámetros.

```
function handleUrl() {
    if (urlDates.start && urlDates.end) {
      return {
        pathname: slug
        query: {
          checkin: urlDates.start,
          checkout: urlDates.end,
        },
      }
    } else {
      return {
        pathname: slug,
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una idea es crear una función "limpiar", así creas tu querystring como lo harías normalmente y luego la pasas por la función "limpiar", que te la retornará sin los elementos undefined

```js
let urlDates = {start:'2002-2-2'};
let slug="localhost";

function handleUrl() {

    let result = { 
    pathname: slug,
      query: {
        checkin: urlDates.start,
        checkout: urlDates.end,
      }
    };
    limpiar(result.query)
    return result;
  }
  
  function limpiar(objeto){
    Object.keys(objeto).forEach(e=>{
      if(!objeto[e]){
        delete objeto[e];
      }
    });
    return objeto;
  }
 
 console.log(handleUrl());
```

Comment: Me sirvio, estaba tratando de pensar una solucion desde el momento que se genera el objeto, pero esto me viene barbaro. Muchas gracias!